# How does OPcache in PHP determine whether a hit how occurred or not?

Tags: php, session, caching, cookies, opcache

What criteria is used to determine whether a cache hit has occurred in PHP OPcache? I would think that things like the request URL, headers, etc. would affect whether a hit occurs or not, but how does OPcache deal with things like pages/scripts that rely on cookies/sessions for rendering the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing PHP Opcache with an HTTP cache.

PHP Opcache doesn't cache the output of a PHP page. Instead, it caches the internal representation used by PHP for a PHP source file, allowing it to be executed immediately when needed, rather than requiring PHP to reparse source files every time a page is requested.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. My understanding was incorrect. So what you're saying is that OPcache simply compiles the PHP files so that from that point on, the compiled version is always used when that filed is accessed, correct? Are APC and Memcached used for similar things? Thank you.

Comment: Precisely, yes. APC is very similar, but memcached is something different.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how is Memcached different?

Comment: memcached is a general purpose data cache. It doesn't do anything on its own, but can be used by an application to cache whatever is appropriate.